# Omitting the word php for opening tags

Tags: php

I mean:

```
<?php echo "hello"; ?>
```

against:

```
<? echo "hello"; ?>
```

(without the `php`).

It works right, but is there any consequence/bad programming practice?? There is no problem?? Is everything OK? What can happen?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: if you ever use xml documents along with php in them then all hell will break loose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paraphrased from the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag):

- `<?php` should always work.
- `<?` only works if `short_open_tag = On` in `php.ini`.
- `<?=` (equivalent to `<?php echo`) should always work in PHP 5.4 and newer. In PHP 5.3 and older, it does require `short_open_tag = On`.

So if you are writing a PHP app for others to use, it is best to stick with `<?php` (and `<?php echo` if you decide to support PHP 5.3 or older). If you can control the server's configuration, you can use `<?` if you want to.

Use, for example, `<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; ?>` if you have to output an XML prolog or processing instruction manually (as opposed to using PHP's [XML functions](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) to do it).

Comment: worth noting `<?=` is identical to `<?php echo `

Answer (score 1):

> It works right, but is there any consequence/bad programming
>   practice?? there is no problem?? is everything ok? what can it happen?

Well, not every hosting allows `short-open-tag`. So `<?php` is a better option if your script target large audience. Or you often change your hosting.

Answer (score 1):

if `short_open_tag` is open, the `short form (<? ?>)` will work.

anyway the `long form` is a standard.